# How to get old classic Document Library view in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Document Library is not showing Custom Master page, how I can get back?

Answer (score 5):

Look at the left - down corner, is that what you are looking for?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please navigate to list settings (you can click to manage views) -> advanced and switch the "List experience" settings 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

- Go to SharePoint Admin Center (`https://mysite-admin.sharepoint.com`) > Settings
- In '**SharePoint Lists and Libraries experience**', select 'Classic experience'

[image]